# MySQL behaviour when using ANY_VALUE multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get a random row for each group when using `GROUP BY` in MySQL 5.7. The most clean way to do it from my research is doing something like this:

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(column_1), ANY_VALUE(column_2), ..., ANY_VALUE(column_n)
FROM table
GROUP BY column
```

Since there is no syntax for something like `ANY_VALUE(*)` or `ANY_VALUE(column_1, column2, ..., column_n)` I am left confused if with the above query each value can come from a different row, or if all `ANY_VALUE` fields will come from the same row.

Comment: `ANY_VALUE(..)` does not ensure that all the columns are going to be from different rows.. it is applied only on a specific column and that specific column can be from any row .. There is still a chance that all the columns may come from the same row (even after any_value)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you mean it does not ensure that they will be from the same row, right?

Comment: @Nikolay . . . It means *any value*.  The values could come from the same row or different rows.  They are certainly not *random* in any technical sense.

Comment: The comments are confusing. ANY_VALUE used as in question works  because of group by, but problem is usage of ANY_VALUE for lots of columns that error because of nonaggregated column. Not sure of comments by Madhur and Gordon

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random row, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I am guessing that this is also faster than `group by`, but you can check if that is the case.

In MySQL 5.7, you can use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = column, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := column, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t.* from t order by column, rand) t cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I think this feature is not available in mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following schema and sample data:

```
create table tbl(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  grp int not null,
  val int not null,
  index (grp)
);

insert into tbl (grp, val) values (1, 1);
insert into tbl (grp, val) values (1, 2);
insert into tbl (grp, val) values (1, 3);
insert into tbl (grp, val) values (2, 1);
insert into tbl (grp, val) values (2, 2);
```

Get distinct groups in a derived table (or use the base table for groups, if you have). Get a random primary key in a subquery in SELECT clause with `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1`. Then join the result as a derived table with the base table.

```
select t.*
from (
  select (
    select id
    from tbl t
    where t.grp = g.grp
    order by rand()
    limit 1
  ) as id
  from (select distinct grp from tbl) g
) r
join tbl t using (id);
```

Result would be something like

```
| id  | grp | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2   | 1   | 2   |
| 4   | 2   | 1   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2L2AiLmjNQ8mJuxPdKnvY/0)